# SQL column maximum input values

Tags: sql

hi please how do i give sql column maximum input example if i want max_num column to take only three(3) result sets or inputs

Comment: You need to edit your question and give us more detail.Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly the same in other rdbms. You need to specify right after the column type

**MYSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
three_char_demo VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
)
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   three_char_demo CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: please i am using MYSQL(SSMS) but you know what thanks for your help at the first place but what i mean is i want the column (rows) to be maximum of three(3) inserts please not the CHAR(3) NOT the characters but the ROWS